# Why New Zealand vs India continued for second day instead of starting from fresh?

Tags: cricket, cricket-world-cup

In world cup 2019 Semi Final, New Zealand vs India continued for second day due 
to the rain. During 2002 ICC Champions Trophy Final, Match cancelled for first day and again played fresh from second day.

Why New Zealand vs India continued for second day instead of starting from fresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious benefit of continuing the match into the second day is that it increases the chance of getting a result, given that there is no guarantee that a full day's play is possible on the second day.

Indeed, the 2002 ICC Champions Trophy demonstrated the risk of starting anew. Despite 52 overs being completed on the first day, and 58 on the reserve day, no result was achieved.

This was [criticized by experienced former players](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/cricket/specials/icc_champions_trophy/2289482.stm) at the time. Farokh Engineer stated

> I think it's absolutely daft. It doesn't make any sense, They should
>   look at that rule straight away and change it. The obvious thing is to
>   continue from where they left off.

and Sanjay Manrekar opined

> The International Cricket Council should learn a lesson from this
>   result ahead of the 2003 World Cup. We had more than 100 overs but
>   still no result. If the match is continued rather than replayed, it
>   gives you more of a chance to finish the game

Maybe there are other contributing reasons, such as tiredness of a team having to field twice, the unfairness of a team in the ascendancy having to start again, and the odd feeling of important contributions being voided (what if you scored a century, or took a hat-trick?), but the huge benefit is the improved chance of a result being achieved.

Answer (score 1):

The regulations covering ODI cricket allow for a reserve day, in the event the match can't be completed on the first day. The umpires are required to try to complete the game on the scheduled day, by reducing overs etc

If this isn't possible, and a reserve day is available, the regs state that the match will continue from the point where it was stopped.

See the regs at https://icc-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2018/09/27/c9264750-2778-44df-949f-d1a8dfbdc402/04-Mens-ODI-Playing-Conditions-2018.pdf - section 13.6 and Appendix G are the relevant sections.